# How to get Current page Title of Relationship Model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

i have some fields in my database table, and i want to display `title`,`description` and `keywords` according to every page, Please let me know how i can display this. My database fields name are `metatitle`,`metadesc`,`keyword`

Here are my Controller code where i am displaying the property list...

```
    public function listtype($slug){
    $prtype= Listing::whereHas('proType',function($q) use($slug){
        $q->where('slug','like','%'.$slug.'%');
    })->paginate(50);
    return view('property-type',compact('prtype','title'));
}
```

Comment: is your Listing model has `metatitle,metadesc,keyword` fields??

Comment: i want title from this `proType`, i can get easily title from `listing` model. But it's difficult to me get the `title from `porType`

Comment: @sainitor You can able to use `with()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following way:

```
 public function listtype($slug){
    $prtype= Listing::whereHas('proType',function($q) use($slug){
        $q->where('slug','like','%'.$slug.'%');
    })->with('proType')->paginate(50);
    dd($prtype); /** for checking **/ 
    return view('property-type',compact('prtype', $prtype));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Bro.. you are great...you solve my problem...i was stuck in this from last 5 hours.